# const values run-time evaluation

Tags: c++

The output of the following code:

```
const int i= 1;
(int&)i= 2;          // or:  const_cast< int&>(i)= 2;
cout << i << endl;
```

is **1** (at least under VS2012)

My question:

- Is this behavior defined?
- Would the compiler always use the defined value for constants?
- Is it possible to construct an example where the compiler would use the value of the latest assignment?

Comment: ub, probably, drop `const`.... and most importantly: are you a language lawyer? :P

Comment: Confirm that the result is 1 under gcc 4.7.2 (Linux), too. If you drop the "const" keyword, then the result becomes 2 (same setup).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said by  others, the behaviour is undefined.

For the sake of completeness, here is the quote from the Standard:

> (§7.1.6.1/4) Except that any class member declared mutable (7.1.1) can be modiﬁed, any attempt to modify a const object during its lifetime (3.8) results in undeﬁned behavior. [ Example:
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> const int* ciq = new const int (3);  // initialized as required
> int* iq = const_cast<int*>(ciq);     // cast required
> *iq = 4;                             // undeﬁned: modiﬁes a const object
> ```
>
> ]

Note that the word *object* is this paragraph refers to all kinds of objects, including simple integers, as shown in the example – not only class objects.

Although the example refers to a pointer to an object with dynamic storage, the text of the paragraph makes it clear that this applies to references to objects with automatic storage as well.

Answer (score 7):

It is totally undefined. You just cannot change the value of constants.

It so happens that the compiler transforms your code into something like

```
cout << 1 << endl;
```

but the program could just as well crash, or do something else.

If you set the warnings level high enough, the compiler will surely tell you that it is not going to work.

Answer (score 4):

> Is this behavior defined?

The behavior of this code is not defined by the C++ standard, because it attempts to modify a const object.

> Would the compiler always use the defined value for constants?

What value the compiler uses in cases like this depends on the implementation. The C++ standard does not impose a requirement.

> Is it possible to construct an example where the compiler would use the value of the latest assignment?

There might be cases where the compiler does modify the value and use it, but they would not be reliable.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is that the behavior is undefined.

I managed to set up this conclusive example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

        const int i = 1;

        int *p=const_cast<int *>(&i);
        *p = 2;
        cout << i << endl;

        cout << *p << endl;

        cout << &i << endl;

        cout << p << endl;

        return 0;
}
```

which, under gcc 4.7.2 gives:

```
1
2
0x7fffa9b7ddf4
0x7fffa9b7ddf4
```

So, it is like you have the same memory address as it is holding two different values.

The most probable explanation is that the compiler simply replaces constant values with their literal values.

Comment: Nice observation! Deleting the 1st line of the main() function and asking a candidate to write it to produce the given output may be a nice interview question...

Comment: @LiorKogan: almost. since the behavior is undefined/implementation independent, the output might be as well 2 and 2 or the examined's computer could start crying. :)

Answer (score -1):

You are doing a `const_cast` using the C-like `cast operator`.

Using `const_cast` is not guaranteeing any behaviour.

if ever you do it, it might work or it might not work.

(It's not good practice to use C-like operators in C++ you know)

Answer (score -2):

Yes you can, but only if you initiate a const as a read-only but not compile-time const, as follows:

```
int y=1;
const int i= y;
(int&)i= 2;
cout << i << endl; // prints 2
```

C++ const keyword can be missleading, it's either a const or a read-only.

Comment: -1 I don't think that answer can begin with the word "yes you can".

Comment: do all compilers are behaving this way ?

Comment: @ Stephane - Works on Visual Studio

Comment: This answer is wrong. Trying to modify a `const` object causes undefined behaviour. (By the way, whether an object declared as `const` is actually compile-time const or run-time const isn't necessarily decidable for the programmer either.)

Comment: @ jogojapan - Funny that you say that the answer is wrong, because I compiled it and it works. And regarding the compile-time/runtime const, you are so wrong, const variable that are decalred like const int x = y; in some cases can be changed at runtime or class const members - also are changed at run time, unless they are static const).

Comment: @StackHeapCollision it is what we are explaining to you: it might work or it might not work - it is undefined behaviour, the C++ standard does'nt guarantee anything about that.

Comment: The answer is wrong because it suggests a way of using C++ that will only work on a specific compiler, and even there in an unreliable way, simply because this behaviour is not defined by the C++ Standard.

Comment: If you consider the original code of the post: const int i = 1; then I agree it would be undefined. But since I offered an alternative: const int i = y; in this case I'm not so sure it is undefined.

Comment: Sure, I understand that this is the reasoning behind your answer. The specific technical reason (or one such reason) for why it is still undefined is that the `const` here enables the compiler to optimize the code: For example, it would be perfectly legal for the compiler to perform `cout << i` _before_ the line that says `(int&)i = 2`, because nothing in that line has an effect on anything in `cout << i` -- except for `i`, but `i` is declared const so the compiler is allowed to assume that it doesn't change. In this particular case optimization may not be useful, but it's impossible to know.

Comment: @jogojapan - It is a lame argument that the solution is wrong just because it spoils for optimization to that code, but it has no undefined behaviour. Ofcourse there will be a spoil for the optimization if you're going to use a read-only variable (read-only, not compile-time constant, e.g: const int x=y), which can be changed on runtime SOMEHOW, but this is a legal solution. Another way around const protection of a read-only variable is: int & j = const_cast<int&>(i) and is legal.

Comment: Look, this _is_ undefined behaviour, because the compiler is free to choose to optimize this (in which case you get 1 as output) or not to optimize it (in which case you get 2). And to be very clear, this is just one example to explain how the undefined behavior may manifest itself. There may be others. The main point is that the Standard explicitly describes this as undefined.